# Unable to click on search box element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can anyone help me figure out how to click in this search box cell to input my data?

Here is the website. I have no issue getting it to click the pop up and then click go to map.

https://isv.kcsgis.com/al.etowah_revenue/

Here is the HTML code from the website:

`<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox" id="widget_dijit_form_TextBox_1" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; display: block;" widgetid="dijit_form_TextBox_1"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_TextBox_1" value=""><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField">1502043000072000</span></div></div>`

Here is the code I have tried using, I have tried other ways as well.

```
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dijit_form_TextBox_3")
search_box.click()
search_box.send_keys("12345")
```

Expecting it to click the search bar and enter the numbers I provide.

Thanks everyone. I got it figured out just to get stuck again...
After you enter a parcel number and click search there is a "more details" button located in the bottom right. Any ideas how to click that. I have tried Xpaths, css_selects and printing the Hrefs off located inside  and  no luck.

```
 # Wait for the "a" elements that are direct children of "i" elements to be present
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//i/a")))

        # Find all "a" elements that are direct children of "i" elements
        i_elements_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//i/a")

        # Extract and print the href attribute for each link
        for link in i_elements_links:
            href = link.get_attribute("href")
            print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong, type:

```
dijit_form_TextBox_1
```

not

```
dijit_form_TextBox_3
```

:

```
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dijit_form_TextBox_1")
search_box.click()
search_box.send_keys("12345")
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I actually dumb luck figured that out. Not sure why inspecting kept giving me textbox3. It just took me from one stuck place to the next lol. Once you enter a parcel number and click search there is a "more details box in bottom left. I can't get that either. Building scripts is easier than digging in HTML lol.

Answer (score 0):

When this website is loaded by the browser, the elements within the page load at different time intervals. This makes locating elements difficult.

if the element you're looking for is not yet present in the DOM, a locate function (like `find_element()`) will raise an exception. We can solve this using `waits`.  An explicit wait makes WebDriver wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further with execution.

You may try the below implementation, it's working and able to input the data in the `textbox`.

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = 'https://isv.kcsgis.com/al.etowah_revenue/'
driver.get(url)

# wait for "I Agree" to click
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dijitDialogPaneActionBar>button')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dijitDialogPaneActionBar>button').click()

# wait for "Go to Maps" to click
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btnClose.btnClose-primary')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btnClose.btnClose-primary').click()

# wait for "Search Tools" to click
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchTools')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchTools').click()

# wait for the "Parcel Number" textbox to enter the number
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'dijit_form_TextBox_3')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dijit_form_TextBox_3').send_keys('24546')

time.sleep(5)
```

I hope this solves the issue and let me know if you face any further problems.

Comment: Thanks I tried that. Problem was the wrong Xpath. Even though clicking inspect on the element it still gave wrong path..